# Count unique values in column by month with blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have 2 columns I am comparing.  One column I want to count unique numbers.  I want to quantify this unique count by month.  (Work Orders per Month).

I'm using:

{=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($L$2:$L$5001=7,$G$2:$G$5001),$G$2:$G$5001),1))}

Where 7 is the value assigned to July (each month get's its own).

I had the formula working with a basic example (single digit WO numbers) and no blanks in the WO column).  I'm not sure where it broke from simple to more complex.  I am far from a pro Excel person but I've been googling the crud out of this for a couple days.  Below is a crude example of the table blanks in the WO Column (I have to keep them this way due to the nature of the data) and a month value in each row of the month column.

```
            7
            7
  39442     7
  39442     7
  39442     7
  39442     7
            7
            7
            7
            7 
  39468     7
  39468     7
  39468     7
  39468     7
  39468     7
```

The count would be output to another table in the same sheet listing each month and the count next to it. Based on the table above I would expect July to have 2 unique work orders (39442 & 39468) I'm only concerned with counting them though, not listing.

Month | Count

July  |    2

I apologize for the poorly constructed table above, however, I don't have the reputation to post a screenshot of the actual sheet.

Thank you in advance.

Mike

Comment: Oh, this certainly sounds like a job for PIVOT TABLE

Comment: Definitely pivot table material - if you haven't used them before, this is a great task to start with.  Highlight your data table, select "Insert" -> "Pivot table" and you're off.  It is really pretty self-explanatory from there out.

Comment: A Pivot Table will not work - they cannot calculate a "unique count".

Comment: I looked at the Pivot table and it looks pretty good.  I'm not familiar with this approach and I'm so close with my current formula that I'd like to explore it a bit more.

If I hand type (including blank cells) that formula works like magic.  If I copy the data into the column it does not.  If I normal paste or paste values.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  It has a Group By command which includes a Count Distinct Rows operation.  It's documented here (although they haven't yet caught up with that operation):

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-rows-in-a-table-Power-Query-e1b9e916-6fcc-40bf-a6e8-ef928240adf1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

For your scenario I would first Filter out the rows with no WO value, then Group By on Month, with a Count Distinct Rows operation.  This would deliver a table with the Month and Unique Count columns.

If you also want Power Query to convert the Month numbers to names, you could do that with an "Add Column" formula, e.g.

`= Date.ToText ( #date ( 2015 , [Month] , 1 ) , "MMMM" )`